# Java stack trace not printing with log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I am sure this is a simple fix but can't for the life of me figure out why. I am getting random NPEs and have log4j (2.0.2) logging the error, however despite having the `%ex` in my log4j configuration file, it prints no stack trace.

> 11-01-2019 02:39:33.212 [Thread-307] ERROR AlarmParse.ProcessAlarm: java.lang.NullPointerException -

Log4j2 configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration monitorInterval="30" status="INFO">
  <appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg - %ex%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="MyFile" fileName="G:/iMCAlarmParse/logs/AppLog.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{2}: %msg - %ex%n"/>
    </File>
```

Java:

```
try {
    //<Many sequential class calls>
} catch (Exception e) {
    log4j.error(e);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By `log4j.error(e)` you are actually invoking `info(Object message)` method which does not take extra care of `Exception`.

But, to print stack trace, you need to invoke one of the variants which handles `Throwable` (super class of Exception) separately. One of the easiest method for this could be `info(CharSequence arg0, Throwable arg1)`.

E.g. you can simply change the line in the catch block to:

```
log4j.error("", e);
```

Comment: Awesome.  I've recompiled and am deploying the JAR to the server.  Now we wait.... :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  The stack trace seems a bit short, but it identified the failing class.

Comment: Try `%ex{full}` for stack trace.